# Google Maps: set zoom in options

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Im using Google Maps, I added 2 markers.

**Online Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/VnwFT/1/

I just need to set a zoom, I tried in `mapOpts` and in `fitBounds` as well:

```
zoom 
minzoom
maxzoom
```

e.x:

```
var mapOpts = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 16
}
```

and it doesn't work.

How Could I set a zoom?

Comment: You need to set the zoom on map initialize or on click in the marker?

Comment: any solution will be fine for me

Comment: What makes you think it isn't working? What is the map doing that you don't like?  I see a map, for that to happen there has to be a zoom set.

Comment: I want to set zoom to a high level, 14 or 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what I've done here:

http://jsfiddle.net/VnwFT/27/

First you need to define the center of the map when you initialize it:

```
var mapOpts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.764043,4.835659),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 16
}
```

Then if you don't need the fitBounds function (the center of the map is already defined on initialize), you could comment it.

Then in the marker click listener you could edit the code to zoom the map on marker click:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function () {
    infoWindow.setOptions(options);
    infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
    if (this.sidebarButton) this.sidebarButton.button.focus();
    map.setZoom(16);
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, if there is a solution to show all markers, and when you click on each one, you will jump to the it

Comment: I've made some changes (and edited my first response), see if is that what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/VnwFT/27/

Comment: I see just one marker on the map, I refresh the link. I'm wrong?

Comment: If you zoom out (on zoom controls), the other is there. You could change the initial zoom tho show all markers.